# In Memory Integration test for web api is failing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

This is my in memory integration test for my Web APi. I am getting "Internal Server Error" as the response for any request. I did not able to identify the issue. Please let me know what's wrong here.....??

```
public void mytest()
        {
            Type sampleTestsControllerType = typeof(WebAPI.Controllers.MyController);
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/GetItem/{ItemId}/{modId}/{country}",
            new
            {
                controller = "My",
                ItemId= UrlParameter.Optional,
                modid= UrlParameter.Optional,
                country= UrlParameter.Optional,
                Action = "GetItem"
            });

            var server = new HttpServer(config);
            using (var client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server))
            {
                using (var request = 
                    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:26581/api/GetItem/201/10/IND")
                    )
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                    Assert.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Found, response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance....

Update: This is how my controller look like...

```
//Arguments null check
        if (IsArgumentNull(param1, param2, param3))
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, GlobalConstants.ArgumentsRequired);
        }

        IContentNegotiator contentNegotiator = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();


        ContentNegotiationResult contentNegotiationResult = contentNegotiator.Negotiate(typeof(returnObject), Request, Configuration.Formatters);


        if (contentNegotiationResult == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, GlobalConstants.NotAcceptable);
        }


        var result= _repository.GetItem(param1, param2, param3);


        if (result== null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, GlobalConstants.NotFound);
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<returnObject>(result, contentNegotiationResult.Formatter, contentNegotiationResult.MediaType.MediaType)
        };
```

Comment: Do you get any error details in the 500 Internal Server response? Also  I noticed that you are disposing the request before the SendAsync call..remove the 'using' statement that you have applied for the request...

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I did not get any error details. And I removed the using for the request. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whats going on...I would have expected more error details in the httpresponse body...Could you share how your controller looks like?

Comment: Please see my update Kiran

Comment: Thanks...your code looks ok...I was looking for the action definitions on your controller to figure out if any selection is causing the 500 error to happen...when you do a 'response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result', you are not seeing any body is it?...sorry but at this point i am not sure whats going on...may be if you can send me the repro, i can help you...